# Wasserstein distance between multivariate lognormal distributions

Tags: normal-distribution, lognormal-distribution, metric, distance-functions, wasserstein

Wikipedia gives the following [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasserstein_metric#Normal_distributions) for normal distributions:
[image]

What changes, if any, do I need to make to handle multivariate lognormal distributions instead?

Comment: The Wasserstein distance is parameterisation dependent, so it will differ for log-normal distributions

Comment: 1) Is that formula correct? It is not in the paper cited by the Wikipedia article, since that paper considers only normal distributions with 0 mean. 2) The phrase "Wasserstein distance" in the title suggests the usual Wasserstein 1-distance, but the formula is for the 2-distance. So it would be better for the title to refer to "Wasserstein 2-distance", or for the formula to be omitted, or (depending on what you want) just to ask for any theoretically-grounded distance with an explicit formula.